# is gas cost affection on remix account's ethereum balance same as the real?

Tags: solidity, remix, gas

most of functions that i execute in remix affects a cost in my test ethereum's balance.
Is this reduced amount equal to the actual cost in the real?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If all of these variables are the same then the cost is the same:

- contract code (including all contracts which are referenced)
- contract state
- used gas price
- sent transaction(s)

In a test network you probably use at least a lower gas price so you lose less Ethers for transaction costs.